# Can VueX's store also emit events to components?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have the following component tree:

```
App
  List
  ItemDetails
    Widget1
    ...
```

- the `List` component has a filters form, those are applied on button press
- `Widget1` has a button which applies another filter (by `id`) to the list, applying that one removes filters from the filter form and vice versa
- the list is also live-updated via polling (later will be via WebSockets), so I have to separate `v-model` of the filter fields in `List` and the actually applied filters (those are in the store)

Currently, I've put the following state to the VueX store:

```
state: {
    filters: {
        // these come from the List's filter panel
        result: '',
        name: '',
        date: '',
        // this one comes from Widget1
        id: '',
    },
    pagination: {
        perPage: 10,
        page: 0,
        total: 0,
    },
    items: [],

    selectedItem: null,
},
```

and both filters from the `List` and from the button in `Widget1` are applied via dispatching the following action to the store:

```
applyFilters ({ state, commit, dispatch }, filters) {
    if(filters.id) {
        for(let filterName in state.filters)
            if(filterName !== 'id')
                filters[filterName] = '';
    } else {
        filters.id = '';
    }
    commit('setFilters', filters);
    commit('setPage', 0);
    dispatch('loadExaminations');
},
```

But here's the problem: the `List` component has its model of filter fields (on press of the button those are gathered and `applyFilters` is dispatched). This works well except when the id filter (from Widget1) is applied, the filter fields in the `List` component are not emptied.

One obvious option to handle this is to move the model of those filter fields to the store as well. That doesn't look that nice since for each field (that uses `v-model`) I have to create a `computed` (in the `List` component) and write a setter and a getter from the store. It seems nicer to send an event from `applyFilters` to `List` saying "empty the filter fields", but I'm not sure if VueX can do this. **Is this possible? Or should I stick with the "move filter fields' model to the store" plan? Or do you know a nice alternative?** I'm aware of the [event bus](https://css-tricks.com/using-event-bus-to-share-props-between-vue-components/) concept, but that one uses `Vue` instance which shouldn't be used in store, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can listen to vuex's actions by using [subscribeAction](https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#subscribeaction).

```js
// List.vue
mounted() {
    this.$store.subscribeAction({
      before: (action, state) => {
        if (action.type === "applyFilters" && action.payload.id) {
          this.emptyComponentFields();
        }
      },
      after: (action, state) => {}
    });
  }
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-79sy5).